# UNION query failing with "double query has incompatible types: Union, varchar"

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, union, amazon-athena

I'm trying to union 2 datasets with different columns in Amazon Athena. The Query is failing with the error below

> line 78:1: column 8 in double query has incompatible types: Union, varchar

As far as I can see all of the columns share the same datatype (mostly double, except for time which is a string). I'm also confused by this type error. It sounds like its saying one column has the type union and another has the type varchar, but that doesn't make any sense.

You'll notice I've surrounded some column names with "", this is just to account for "-" characters which SQL isn't parsing

I've also changed all of the column names here so if something is off that's why

```
CREATE
        OR REPLACE VIEW combined_dataset AS
SELECT time,
         RRLTTR001,
         RRLTTR002,
         XXTRL001m,
         XXTRL002m,
         XXTRL003m,
         XXTRL004m,
         TYLLO001,
         XXTRL005m,
         ERTLT035,
         ERTLT036,
         ERTLT034,
         ERTLT001,
         ERTLT002,
         ERTLT003,
         ERTLT004,
         XXTRL006m,
         XXTRL007m,
         ERTLT005,
         ERTLT006,
         ERTLT007,
         ERTLT008,
         ERTLT009,
         XXTRL008m,
         XXTRL009m,
         ERTLT010,
         ERTLT011,
         ERTLT012,
         ERTLT013,
         ERTLT014,
         XXTRL010m,
         XXTRL011m,
         ERTLT015,
         ERTLT016,
         ERTLT017,
         ERTLT018,
         ORTEX001,
         ORTEX002,
         ORTEX003,
         XXTRL012m,
         XXTRL013m,
         ERTLT019,
         ERTLT020,
         ERTLT021,
         ERTLT022,
         ERTLT023,
         ERTLT024,
         ERTLT025,
         ERTLT026,
         XXTRL014m,
         TYLLO002,
         XXTRL015m,
         XXTRL016m,
         ERTLT027,
         ERTLT028,
         XXTRL017m,
         XXTRL018m,
         XXTRL019m,
         ERTLT029,
         ERTLT030,
         ERTLT031,
         ERTLT032,
         ERTLT033,
         TYLLO003,
         ORTEX004,
         ORTEX005,
         ORTEX006,
         ORTEX007,
         ORTEX008,
         location,
         facility,
         NULL AS "TRTL0-p",
         NULL AS "CCYLY-p",
         NULL AS "FFoooliPLP-p"
FROM dataset_1
UNION
SELECT Time,
         RRLTTR001,
         RRLTTR002,
         XXTRL001m,
         XXTRL002m,
         XXTRL003m,
         XXTRL004m,
         "FFoooliPLP-p",
         XXTRL005m,
         ERTLT001,
         ERTLT002,
         ERTLT003,
         ERTLT004,
         XXTRL006m,
         XXTRL007m,
         ERTLT005,
         ERTLT006,
         ERTLT007,
         ERTLT008,
         ERTLT009,
         XXTRL008m,
         XXTRL009m,
         ERTLT010,
         ERTLT011,
         ERTLT012,
         ERTLT013,
         ERTLT014,
         XXTRL010m,
         XXTRL011m,
         ERTLT015,
         ERTLT016,
         ERTLT017,
         ERTLT018,
         ORTEX001,
         ORTEX002,
         ORTEX003,
         XXTRL012m,
         XXTRL013m,
         ERTLT019,
         ERTLT020,
         ERTLT021,
         ERTLT022,
         ERTLT023,
         ERTLT024,
         ERTLT025,
         ERTLT026,
         XXTRL014m,
         "CCYLY-p",
         XXTRL015m,
         XXTRL016m,
         ERTLT027,
         ERTLT028,
         XXTRL017m,
         XXTRL018m,
         XXTRL019m,
         ERTLT029,
         ERTLT030,
         ERTLT031,
         ERTLT032,
         ERTLT033,
         "TRTL0-p",
         ORTEX007,
         ORTEX008,
         ERTLT034,
         ERTLT035,
         ERTLT036,
         location,
         facility,
         NULL AS ORTEX006,
         NULL AS ORTEX005,
         NULL AS ORTEX004,
         NULL AS TYLLO001,
         NULL AS TYLLO002,
         NULL AS TYLLO003
FROM dataset_2
```

I've checked the datatypes and everything looks fine. Have also googled around on this and found nothing. It has to be a simple problem, I just don't know what to look for

EDIT: Here are the table definitions guys, let me know if you spot something I missed. I had to redo the substitutions so if you see any names that look screwed up its probably an error I made while modifying the schemas for this post

Dataset 1

```
1   time    string
2   RRLTTR001   double
3   RRLTTR002   double
4   XXTRL001m   double
5   XXTRL002m   double
6   XXTRL003m   double
7   XXTRL004m   double
8   TYLLO001    double
9   XXTRL005m   double
10  ERTLT035    double
11  ERTLT036    double
12  ERTLT034    double
13  ERTLT001    double
14  ERTLT002    double
15  ERTLT003    double
16  ERTLT004    double
17  XXTRL006m   double
18  XXTRL007m   double
19  ERTLT005    double
20  ERTLT006    double
21  ERTLT007    double
22  ERTLT008    double
23  ERTLT009    double
24  XXTRL008m   double
25  XXTRL009m   double
26  ERTLT010    double
27  ERTLT011    double
28  ERTLT012    double
29  ERTLT013    double
30  ERTLT014    double
31  XXTRL010m   double
32  XXTRL011m   double
33  ERTLT015    double
34  ERTLT016    double
35  ERTLT017    double
36  ERTLT018    double
37  ORTEX001    double
38  ORTEX002    double
39  ORTEX003    double
40  XXTRL012m   double
41  XXTRL013m   double
42  ERTLT019    double
43  ERTLT020    double
44  ERTLT021    double
45  ERTLT022    double
46  ERTLT023    double
47  ERTLT024    double
48  ERTLT025    double
49  ERTLT026    double
50  XXTRL014m   double
51  TYLLO002    double
52  XXTRL015m   double
53  XXTRL016m   double
54  ERTLT027    double
55  ERTLT028    double
56  XXTRL017m   double
57  XXTRL018m   double
58  XXTRL019m   double
59  ERTLT029    double
60  ERTLT030    double
61  ERTLT031    double
62  ERTLT032    double
63  ERTLT033    double
64  TYLLO003    double
65  ORTEX004    double
66  ORTEX005    double
67  ORTEX006    double
68  ORTEX007    double
69  ORTEX008    double
70  location    string
71  facility    string
```

dataset 2

```
1   time    string
2   RRLTTR001   double
3   RRLTTR002   double
4   XXTRL001m   double
5   XXTRL002m   double
6   XXTRL003m   double
7   XXTRL004m   double
8   FFoooliPLP-p    double
9   XXTRL005m   string
10  ERTLT001    double
11  ERTLT002    double
12  ERTLT003    double
13  ERTLT004    double
14  XXTRL006m   double
15  XXTRL007m   double
16  ERTLT005    double
17  ERTLT006    double
18  ERTLT007    double
19  ERTLT008    double
20  ERTLT009    double
21  XXTRL008m   double
22  XXTRL009m   double
23  ERTLT010    double
24  ERTLT011    double
25  ERTLT012    double
26  ERTLT013    double
27  ERTLT014    double
28  XXTRL010m   double
29  XXTRL011m   double
30  ERTLT015    double
31  ERTLT016    double
32  ERTLT017    double
33  ERTLT018    double
34  ORTEX001    double
35  ORTEX002    double
36  ORTEX003    double
37  XXTRL012m   double
38  XXTRL013m   double
39  ERTLT019    double
40  ERTLT020    double
41  ERTLT021    double
42  ERTLT022    double
43  ERTLT023    double
44  ERTLT024    double
45  ERTLT025    double
46  ERTLT026    double
47  XXTRL014m   double
48  CCYLY-p double
49  XXTRL015m   double
50  XXTRL016m   double
51  ERTLT027    double
52  ERTLT028    double
53  XXTRL017m   double
54  XXTRL018m   double
55  XXTRL019m   double
56  ERTLT029    double
57  ERTLT030    double
58  ERTLT031    double
59  ERTLT032    double
60  ERTLT033    double
61  TRTL0-p     double
62  ORTEX007    double
63  ORTEX008    double
64  ERTLT034    double
65  ERTLT035    double
66  ERTLT036    double
67  location    string
68  facility    string
```

Comment: Given the massive size of the query, we can't really help you without seeing table definitions both tables.  Inspecting that should easily reveal the source of the problem.

Comment: I wonder if tthe coders at Amazon got the message formatting wrong. It would make more sense to me if the message said *"line 78:1: column 8 in union query has incompatible types: double, varchar"* - perhaps they coded `format("column {0} in {1} query has incompatible types: {2}, {3}", colNum, faultyType1, queryType, faultyType2)` ie getting placeholder variables in the wrong order. However it happens it seems to be saying one of your columns (on line 78?) is a double and the equivalent column on the other side of the union is a string. Double (hah) check all your column types?

Comment: Yes agreed Caius, I think this is the culprit

Comment: Hey @TimBiegeleisen, table schemas are above

Comment: So XXTRL005m is a double in dataset1 and a string in dataset 2.. you say this has been checked and factored in; where does your query do this ?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned mostly all columns are double and both tables are having same datatypes, i only can see few field like "FFoooliPLP-p" ,"CCYLY-p" ,"TRTL0-p" as hard coded in dataset_2 table which could be culprits or  ORTEX008,location,facility fields from dataset_1 table  which can be of different datatype.

If doesn't resolve then please share table structures.

Comment: Hey Ram, shared the table structures

Comment: Thanks @ronaldmcdolittle,   i could identify  "XXTRL005m" field's datatype different in both the tables.                                                                        Apart from this ORTEX006, ORTEX007 (from dataset 1) and location,facility, (from dataset 2) in union selection query looks different with datatype.